# unmanaged task in linux

Tags: linux, ssh, expect, telnet

I trying to create a unmanaged script to manage my tp-link switch (change state, description, and speed,...). Tp-link uses a similar connection that cisco... for example: Deactivate a port:

```
enable
configure
interface gigabitEthernet 1/0/20
shutdown
```

If I connect to my switch (with ssh) I can execute all commands without problems but I use command line don't works:

For example:

```
ssh x.x.x.x "sh interface configuration"
```

This command should be show the status of my ports but not shows nothing. User and password is ok. SSH returns:

```
Authenticated with partial success.
Connection to 192.168.20.26 closed by remote host.
```

Can you says other options to execute this?

I try this execute this options with expect and telnet and results is ok but if I executed expect with ssh connection don't works neither.

My expect script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn -noecho telnet 192.168.20.26

expect "User:"
send -- "admin\r"
expect "Password:"
send -- "mypass\r"
send -- "enable\r"
send -- "configure\r"
send -- "interface gigabitEthernet 1/0/20\r"
send -- "description hola\r"
send -- "exit\r"
send -- "exit\r"
send -- "exit\r"
send -- "exit\r"
send -- "exit\r"

interact
```

The script works fine but if I execute this script from remote host don't works.

Best regards.

Comment: If you provide some expect code that doesn't work - we could help, otherwise the question is a bit too generic.

Comment: Hi @favoretti. I edited my post with the expect script. The problem not is the script. This works fine, but if I execute expect with remote host not works (don't login).

Comment: So when you replace `telnet` with `ssh` there, it does nothing? Have you tried using `ssh -T` (don't allocate PTY).

Comment: oh yes @favoretti If I use ssh -t works fine. Thanks!!

Comment: Added it as an answer. You used lowercase `-t`, right? So basically forced PTY allocation?

Comment: @favoretti oh not works. I try to explain but my english is bad. Wait a moment.

Comment: Okey, If I use ssh -t in my host to connect to the host hosted the script works fine but I can't use this. I have a plataform in php. This intranet makes a connection with a host and this host have ssh -t to the host of hosted expect script. I believe that first connection (maked with php) haven't option "-t". Sorry @favoretti not mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The problem above was caused by the fact that ssh failed to allocate PTY automatically. `ssh -t` fixed the issue.